# Change is_numeric to check all values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have this code:

```
foreach($feed['posts'][$i] as $key => $value)
{
  $sql[] = (is_numeric($value)) ? "`$key` = $value" : "`$key` = '" . "'";
}
$sqlclause = implode(",",$sql);
```

This works fine, but it only fills in the values that have a number.
If I take the is_numeric or change it into `($value)` or different variants of it, the query does completes, but no data is added to my MySQL database.

Comment: please use PDO for constructing SQL queries!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe because you're not adding a value if the value is not numeric:

```
$sql[] = (is_numeric($value)) ? "`$key` = $value" : "`$key` = '" . $value . "'";
//                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```